# Limit of the floor function of $\frac{x}{\sin(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Alright this looks like a very simple problem at the first go.

I need to find $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+} { \left\lfloor{\frac{x}{\sin (x)}}\right\rfloor}$$

So since I know the inner function's graph beforehand I know the answer will be 1.

But now here's my problem.When I'm trying to find which function $x$ or $\sin(x)$ is greater when $x \rightarrow 0^+$ I take a function $g(x)=x-\sin(x)$ and find its derivative.So $g'(x)=1-\cos(x)$.Now when I find $g'(x \rightarrow 0^+)$ I get $0$ !

So I'm not being able to prove that $g(x)$ is increasing when $x$ is slightly greater than $0$.And thus I can't prove that $x>sin(x)$ when $x$ is slighty greater than $0$ and neither can I prove $\frac{x}{\sin (x)}>1$.Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think you're thinking of $\displaystyle{\sin x \over x}$, TheGreatDuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $g(x) = x - \sin x$ we have $g'(x) = 1 - \cos x > 0$ for $0 < x \leqslant \pi/2$.  and $g(0) = 0$. By the mean value theorem for any $x$ in the interval there exists $\xi$ between $0$ and $x$ such that $g(x) = g'(\xi)x > 0.$

Comment: What does this $g(x) = g'(\xi)x > 0$ mean ?

Comment: Can you please clarify that last notation?

Comment: I added above.  Use the mean value theorem $g(x) - g(0) = g'(\xi)(x- 0)$ for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $x$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a  ["classical" proof](http://mathrefresher.blogspot.in/2006/08/sin-x-x-tan-x-for-x-in-02.html) (based on geometry and trigonometry) that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} {\sin x \over x} = 1$. In it, it is proven that $\sin x < x < \tan x$ when $x>0$ and is small. It should be in any Calculus textbook.

Dividing this equation through by $\sin x$, you get $\displaystyle 1 < {x\over \sin x}$, when $x>0$ and $x$ is small. Hence $\displaystyle\left\lfloor {x\over \sin x}\right\rfloor \ge 1$ for those same $x$.

Comment: Read the question....

Comment: There might be several ways of proving that claim.But what I am looking for is a calculus based proof (without taylor series).And my doubt is why is the general method of taking the difference of two functions and finding its derivative to find out which function is greater is not working here.

Comment: Looking at your original post, $g'(x)>0$ when $x>0$ and small, because $\cos x < 1$. Thus, $g$ is increasing on $(0,\varepsilon)$ for small $\epsilon$. (And, BTW, I didn't use Taylor Series.)

Comment: Okay thanks :-)

Comment: I think you're thinking of $\displaystyle{\sin x \over x}$, TheGreatDuck.